# Profiling, Leaks tool causes instruments to crash

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, instruments

I've searched around for people having similar problems, but to no avail.  I'm trying to test my app for memory leaks, but when I try to use the leaks tool, it causes the instruments program to crash after around 10 seconds, this happens with all apps, including ones I know to be leak free and no other tools in instruments does this. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uninstall and install the xcode again, once it happen with me with xcode 4.2, I just reinstalled and after its working fine.